# Lucene.net extract query parts from boolean query

Tags: lucene, boolean, lucene.net

I want to extract my boolean query into parts.
If I have a query like this:

```
"Zlatan AND Milan OR (Juventus OR Inter) NOT (Pelle OR Lisa)"
```

I want to extract it into

Keywords = ["Zlatan","Milan"]

Includes = ["Juventus", "Inter"]

Excludes = ["Pelle", "Lisa"]

The code I have tried looks like this:

```
var q = "Zlatan AND Milan OR (Juventus OR Inter) NOT (Pelle OR Lisa)";
Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(LuceneVersion.LUCENE_48);
var parser = new QueryParser(LuceneVersion.LUCENE_48, "", analyzer);
Lucene.Net.Search.BooleanQuery bquery = new Lucene.Net.Search.BooleanQuery();
Query parsedQuery = parser.Parse(q);
bquery.Add(parsedQuery, Occur.MUST);
var terms = new HashSet<Term>();
bquery.ExtractTerms(terms);
```

But then I only get the terms:

[image]

So I don't know what are my keywords etc.
And the query looks like this when it's parsed:

```
+(+zlatan +milan (juventus inter) -(pelle lisa)
```

Comment: How is the boolean query string created in the first place?

Comment: It's user input that is parsed using lucene: https://github.com/thoward/lucene-query-parser.js/wiki @andrewjames

Comment: Thank you. If the users just write the full query string themselves, then I think you would have to write your own parser - either on the original query expression string or (probably better) on the parsed query string. I am not aware of anything in Lucene which can get you closer than that to the output you want. (Or, maybe change the input interface, so users have to enter their query in a structured way up-front?)